# Why does setting css left property result in it going off by 8?

Tags: javascript, css

Here is a fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/p31L86wg/4/

Ideally, the green box should always be in the centre of the container, but for some reason when I set the left property it is choosing to stop 8 pixels before the pixel value I tell it to assume.

```
angular.module('website', ['ngAnimate'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.products = [
        {name: 'p1'},
        {name: 'p2'},
        {name: 'p3'},
        {name: 'p4'},
        {name: 'p5'}
    ];
    $scope.currentIndex = 0;

    $scope.setCurrentSlideIndex = function (index) {
        $scope.currentIndex = index;
    };

    $scope.isCurrentSlideIndex = function (index) {
        return $scope.currentIndex === index;
    };
})
.directive('pan', function(panBuckets) {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        elm.css('position', 'relative');
        var parentWidth = elm.parent().width();
        elm.css('left', Math.floor(parentWidth/2)-(70/2)+'px');
        scope.pan = function(vector) {
          var bucket = panBuckets[attr['pan']];
          if (bucket) {
              var result = bucket.selectNewItem(bucket.selectedIndex-vector);
              var rect = elm[0].getBoundingClientRect();
              console.log('amount moved',rect.left, (vector*70)+'px',rect.left+(vector*70)+'px');
              if (result!==false) elm.css('left', rect.left+(vector*70)+'px');
              console.log(bucket.selectedItem[0].getBoundingClientRect().left, rect.left);
          }
        };
    };
})
.service('panBuckets', function() {
    return {};   
})
.directive('panItem', function(panBuckets) {
    var itemBuckets = panBuckets;
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var bucket = itemBuckets[attr['panItem']];
        if (!bucket) {
            itemBuckets[attr['panItem']] = [];
            bucket = itemBuckets[attr['panItem']];
            elm.addClass('product-active');
            bucket.selectedItem = elm;
            bucket.selectNewItem = function(idx) {
                if (idx < 0) idx = 0;
                if (bucket.selectedIndex==idx) return false;
                if (!bucket[idx]) return false;                
                bucket.selectedItem.removeClass('product-active');
                bucket.selectedItem = bucket[idx];
                bucket.selectedItem.addClass('product-active');
                bucket.selectedIndex = idx;
                return idx;
            };
            bucket.selectedIndex = 0;
        }
        bucket.push(elm);
        scope.panBucket = bucket;
    };
})
;
```

Comment: please note that if you click the button multiple times before previous animation has ended it yields unexpected behavior (the green box is not in the middle)

Comment: Yeah, but even if you don't click multiple times before previous animation it is still all messed up by 8px every time.

Answer (score 0):

Position relative is a bit weird when trying to achieve such positioning, because it keeps the item 'inplace' and then repositions it, it can create some weird behaviors.

A working and easy solution is to change the position of the boxes container to absolute, and the container to relative. that way precision is guaranteed.

P.s. a little off topic, but animations this way (moving elements around) is better done with transform translate, it's a lot faster (the processing goes off to the GPU when possible and some more optimizations).

Comment: I already set it to absolute and the parent to "relative" and it still was the same exact behaviour.  Thanks for the tip about using transform.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('website', ['ngAnimate'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) { 
        $scope.products = [
            {name: 'p1'},
            {name: 'p2'},
            {name: 'p3'},
            {name: 'p4'},
            {name: 'p5'}
        ];
        $scope.currentIndex = 0;

        $scope.setCurrentSlideIndex = function (index) {
            $scope.currentIndex = index;
        };

        $scope.isCurrentSlideIndex = function (index) {
            return $scope.currentIndex === index;
        };
    })
.directive('pan', function(panBuckets) {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {;
        elm.css('position', 'relative');
        var parentWidth = elm.parent().width();
        elm.css('left', Math.floor(parentWidth/2)-(70/2)+'px');
        scope.pan = function(vector) {
          var bucket = panBuckets[attr['pan']];
          if (bucket) {
              var result = bucket.selectNewItem(bucket.selectedIndex+vector);
              var rect = elm[0].getBoundingClientRect();
              var bucketDimensions = bucket.selectedItem[0].getBoundingClientRect();
              console.log(bucketDimensions);
              if (result !== false) elm.css('left', Math.floor(parentWidth/2)-parseInt(bucket.selectedIndex * 70)-(70/2)+'px');
          }
        };
    };
})
.service('panBuckets', function() {
    return {};   
})
.directive('panItem', function(panBuckets) {
    var itemBuckets = panBuckets;
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var bucket = itemBuckets[attr['panItem']];
        if (!bucket) {
            itemBuckets[attr['panItem']] = [];
            bucket = itemBuckets[attr['panItem']];
            elm.addClass('product-active');
            bucket.selectedItem = elm;
            bucket.selectNewItem = function(idx) {
                if (idx < 0) idx = 0;
                if (bucket.selectedIndex==idx) return false;
                if (!bucket[idx]) return false;                
                bucket.selectedItem.removeClass('product-active');
                bucket.selectedItem = bucket[idx];
                bucket.selectedItem.addClass('product-active');
                bucket.selectedIndex = idx;
                return idx;
            };
            bucket.selectedIndex = 0;
        }
        bucket.push(elm);
        scope.panBucket = bucket;
    };
})
;
```

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.product-active {
    background: green !important;
}

.square {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    background: blue;
}

.slider {
    width:492px;
    margin:0;
    transition-property: left;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-timing-: function: linear;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.10.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-animate.js"></script>

<div ng-app="website" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div class="container">
    <div class="slider animated zoomIn" pan="one">
    <div ng-repeat="p in products" class="square product" pan-item="one">{{p.name}}      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <button ng-click="pan(-1)"><</button>
    <button ng-click="pan(1)">></button>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2u29LL3L/1/

There were some inconsistencies, check the diff, I think it's how you were trying to achieve.

I didn't understand why you had `70` instead of `50` in your math, but then I saw it's because of the margin.

I basically changed the calculation of left position of slider:

```
if (result !== false) elm.css('left', Math.floor(parentWidth/2)-parseInt(bucket.selectedIndex * 70)-(70/2)+'px');
```

So everytime, `Math.floor(parentWidth/2)` centers the slider, then puts the selected bins to the left with `-parseInt(bucket.selectedIndex * 70)` and then takes half of the current bin to the left.

I removed margin and padding of `body`, check it.

### EDIT

I changed also the orientation of pan, now it seems more like it =)

Answer (score 0):

From first glance, it appears that the green box has both left and right margin.

```
.square:first-child {margin-left:0px;}
```

This will remove margin on the left and will allow the box to adjust back towards the left, where you want it.